# Sending the current key to a create view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

So on my details page I have the main project with a list of project assets.

On this page, I have a "Create New Asset" button.  What I want done is to take the Primary key of the project, send it to the Create Asset page, and have the Project Id being the Primary key passed from the previous.

First:

```
@Html.ActionLink("New Asset", "CreateAsset", new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
```

This will send the primary key out.

Then:

```
public ActionResult CreateAsset(int? id)
{
    ViewBag.AreaId = new SelectList(db.areas, "Id", "Name");
    ViewBag.ProjectId = id;
    return View();
}
```

I've created a ViewBag to store the received Primary Key.

Finally and this is where I'm stuck, so I want to do something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProjectId, new { @Value = ViewBag.ProjectId })
```

Which doesn't work, so how does one create a TextBox that the model would acknowledge?

I can't test the HTTPost yet because of this last part but I believe that on post it will create a new Asset key and ignore the Primary key I passed from the Project Detail page.

Comment: What is not working for you? Can you tell me what exactly are you looking out for?

Comment: I'm trying to have a create Asset page that take the key from the Projects page and adds it to the ProjectId of the Asset table.  The issue is the AssetId is database generated and its inheriting the value of the ProjectId.

Comment: Update:  Solution is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is ProjectID a property of the new Asset you want to create ? If yes, why not simply send a new instance of the Asset class with the ProjectID pre-populated ?

```
public ActionResult CreateAsset(int? id)
{
    Foo newFoo = new Foo();
    ViewBag.AreaId = new SelectList(db.areas, "Id", "Name");
    foo.ProjectId = id;
    return View(newFoo);
}
```

This way, you don't have to handle anything manually with the ViewBag in the UI.

Comment: Yes Project(Id) is the parent table of Assets(Asset.Id) table.  So instead of them going to Assets and using a dropdown to select the Project.  The Project Name(Project.Id) will be pre-filled.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  Okay this method does work to an extent.  However, on HttpPost the Asset id is inheriting the value of the ProjectId when passed.  I'm trying to find a way to null the AssetId so on db.asset.Add(asset) it automatically generates the proper AssetId.

Comment: Oop.  I just did some testing and it turns out the database doesnt care what value the entity sends on add.